# is it required to mvn clean install before mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Pulled an existing project form Git Repo

I tried running it using `mvn spring-boot:run` , but it gave error

Then performed a `mvn clean install` then did `mvn spring-boot:run`, and it got running !!!

Earlier I was supposing `mvn spring-boot:run` performs the task of `mvn clean install` also !

But then, How does `mvn spring-boot:run` considers latest code at compilation (I mean if it is not doing `install` it should not be compiling, so it should be running the stale JAR, but it takes the new code changes and refreshes the JAR)

Can somebody through some light on the confusion !

Comment: The only needed part is `mvn package spring-boot:run`. It could be usefull to use `mvn verify` cause that will run integration tests (if you have some in your project). I strongly recommend to read https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 4):

`mvn clean install` is used to resolve dependencies that are listed on your `pom.xml`. You don't need to run it if there are no changes to your `pom.xml`. The error was most likely due to your local not having all the dependencies required.

Comment: Intellij auto downloads when I do some pom changes at dependencies. Is this ```mvn install``` running at backgroud ?

Comment: No. IntelliJ has its own way of managing project structure & (maven) dependencies, as it simply reads the pom.xml AFAIK. Its why you would see metadata files with `.iml` and `.idea` extensions. However, IntelliJ is integrated with Maven and can be used to execute different Maven goals if that's what you want to do. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between `mvn spring-boot:run` and `mvn clean install` is the later phases after `testCompile` phase. Please refer to attached screenshots.

`mvn spring-boot:run`

[image]

`mvn clean install`

[image]

The later steps after running tests in mvn clean install are -

> Building jar, repackage, install (default-install)

However as compilation is done, so any changes in source code must be reflected in either case.